# Getting child values from firebase to android app

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am having issues getting my .child items which are on my firebase displaying on my listview on my android application.

When I use the following code:

```
String value = dataSnapshot.child("messages").getValue(String.class);
            list.add(value);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

I am able to retrieve the data, but when a change is made to the firebase, all the data is removed and it displays the new entry.

I want to be able to retrieve .child entries from the database for example

```
fDatabase.child("messages").child("message").addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener()
```

I would only want it to display, update and change the child messages.

Can somebody help me out, the connection to database is fine, the app is not crashing. just disconnecting due to inactivity.

Could this be a permissions thing on firebase?

My firebase rules are currently set public which i am aware off

```
{
  "rules": {
    "messages":{
    ".read": true,
    ".write":true,  
}
}
  }
```

Any advice ?

My code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
DatabaseReference fDatabase;
ListView listview;
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayAdapter <String> adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, list);
    listview.setAdapter(adapter);


    fDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();


    fDatabase.child("messages").child("message").addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            String value = dataSnapshot.child("messages").getValue(String.class);
            adapter.add((String)dataSnapshot.child("messages").getValue());
            list.add(value);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            adapter.clear();
            adapter.add((String)dataSnapshot.child("messages").getValue());
            String value = dataSnapshot.child("messages").getValue(String.class);
            list.add(value);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {


        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
}
```

I have looked at this question but cant get it working either

[Get child ID from Firebase android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41348891/get-child-id-from-firebase-android)

When i change my code to event listener, i get back null : null : null

```
 protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
    listview.setAdapter(adapter);


    fDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();


    fDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot messageSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                adapter.clear();
                String temp = (String) messageSnapshot.child("temp").getValue();
                String humi = (String) messageSnapshot.child("humi").getValue();
                String status = (String) messageSnapshot.child("status").getValue();
                adapter.add(humi + " : " + temp + " : " + status);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
```

Database structure

```
jmproject-*****
 humi: "77"
 status: "true"
 temp: "24c"
```

Database rules

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write":true,  
}
}
```

Comment: check this library provided by firebase. [Using FirebaseUI to Populate a ListView](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/database/README.md#using-firebaseui-to-populate-a-listview)

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting your data under the message child. What you are looking for is dataSnapshot.getChildren(), which will return a list of all children. The issue with your implementation is you are storing just on child under the "message" key. If you want to store multiple values you need to change the key each time you store a message.

If you want to generate key automatically you can use this

```
String key = firebaseRef.child("messages").push().getKey();
```

This will create a new unique entry under the /messages/ path. Then you can save your data using this key.

Comment: But using getChildren will not work with my String, is there another option ?

Comment: I have changed my code now, im getting the result back as null : null : null, i have updated the question

Comment: You need to add your database structure from firebase. Otherwise i can not help you.

Comment: I have added the structure from firebase.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are setting adapter in oncrete method and not in onChildAdded and onChildChanged methods. You should place the **listView.setAdapter(adapter)** in the childEventListener methods try it. And also your code in ChildAdded and ChildChanged is redundant. Place the code in a method and call the method from your event Listener methods.