# How to get child of only First id in users table

Tags: firebase, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database

I am using android studio which is connected to *Firebase database*
I only want to fetch first id from users table how can I do that?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, assuming that you know the ID already, which is `userID`

```
private DatabaseReference mDatabase;
mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child(userId);    

  ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
  @Override
  public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

    // Manipulate your data here

  }

  @Override
  public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for answering
can you please tell the code to write in manipulate your date here ?

Comment: You can use `userClassObject = getValue(userClass.class)` to get all your user info. I suggest you read the official docs to get more idea on what DataSnapshot is and how fetch desired data from it. https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DataSnapshot

Answer (score 0):

You will have to access the node's children in order to get their values, as far as I understand. 
You can check this other posts in order to better understand how: [Getting children data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30564735/android-firebase-simply-get-one-child-objects-data) and [Getting children ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41348891/get-child-id-from-firebase-android)